# Introducing Arrow(directed), in Force Directed Graph d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am using the force-directed graph in the sample here - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

But since my data is directed, I need the links in the graph to be represented as arrow connections. Maybe like in, http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278.

Can someone please suggest the alterations or additions that create a directed graph as in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I am new to D3, and I couldn't find a solution, maybe its trivial, but a little help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you find it easier to use a library I created: http://jsnetworkx.org/examples.html#example1 (it uses d3).

Comment: @FelixKling This is wonderful ! I think I will try this out now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Merging these two examples is straightforward, and I created a [JSFiddle to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/ncwuej9j/). First, add the definition of the arrow style to the SVG:

```
// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

Then just add the marker to your `links`

```
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

You end up with something like this:

[image]

You'll see that some arrows are bigger than others, because not all links have the same `stroke-width`. If you want to make all the arrows the same size, just modify

```
.style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
```

when adding the links.