# force-directed d3.js add edge labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I want to visualize a graph in d3js with the force-directed layout. I have been following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050434/introducing-arrowdirected-in-force-directed-graph-d3), but I don't get it to work.

I created an jsfiddle, which can be found [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/riasc/zh677re5/46/)
However, now the lines are not working, but the labels are how they should be. Oddly, when I execute it locally it is working but someday lines are shown twice, like this:

```
<g class="link-g">
      <line class="link" x1="297.0210832552382" y1="122.48446414068198" x2="245.8066880510027" y2="240.1061616356794"></line>
      <text>interaction</text>
      <text x="271.4138856531205" y="181.2953128881807">interaction</text>
</g>
```

Anyway, what I do is the following. First the link and linktext.

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
     .data(links, function(d) { 
          return d.source.id + '-' + d.target.id; 
     });

 link.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class","link-g")
      .append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

 link.exit().remove();

 var linktext = svg.selectAll(".link-g")
      .append("text")
      .text("label");
```

Then in the tick():

```
link.attr("x1", function(d) { 
          return d.source.x; 
     })
     .attr("y1", function(d) { 
         return d.source.y; 
     })
     .attr("x2", function(d) { 
          return d.target.x; 
     })
     .attr("y2", function(d) { 
         return d.target.y;
     });
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add attributes `x1, x2, y1, y2` on the `svg:g` element instead of the `line`, that's why there is no visible links.

If you check the code : `svg:g` elements have good values, and `line` got no attribute.

Create a new variable to store your links, and add attributes on this variable:

```
var linkLine = link.enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class","link-g")
   .append("line")
   .attr("class", "link");
```

And update tick function

```
function tick(){
    linkLine.attr("x1", function(d) { 
        return d.source.x; 
    })
    /* ... (others attr) ... */
}
```