# force directed graph d3.js customize arrow color

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I follow the tutorial from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 and questions [Introducing Arrow(directed), in Force Directed Graph d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050434/introducing-arrowdirected-in-force-directed-graph-d3) , and could customize edges color by

```
  var svg_edges = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
                        .data(force.links())
                        .enter()
                        .append("line")
                        .style("stroke",function(d,i){
                         return color(i); // customize edges colors
                        })
```

and then add arrow by the below code:

```
        svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(['end'])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
      .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
        .attr("id", function(d,i) { 
            return d; 
        })
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 15)
        .attr("refY", 0)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
        .style("fill", "#ccc")  // how to customize each arrow color here
```

and then add below in edges

```
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

I want know how to specify each arrow's color just like what we did on edges. 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292 show how to specify different types of edges and arrows, but I did not find ways to change both(arrow and edges) by coding.

Comment: change the `.fill` callback?

Comment: can you show example code?

Comment: You've already done it with `.style("stroke", function(d,i)..)` the function is the callback so rather than giving a static color `.style("fill", "#ccc")` change the `#ccc` with a function.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to style instances of your markers individually, you are out of luck with SVG 1.1. Have a look  at [*"Changing an SVG marker's color - CSS?"*](/q/16664584) for an explanation. You need to define a marker for every color you like and assign that specific marker to the path.

Answer (score 1):

add edges class, in my test, d["value] in {0, 1}

```
 svg_edges.attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#arrow" + d["value"] + ")"; });
```

in arrow definition

```
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
   .data(['0','1'])      //same as  d["value] in {0, 1}
   .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
   .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "arrow" + d; })
```

in css style

```
#arrow0 {
    fill: #ccc;
} 
#arrow1 {
    fill: red;
}
```

Then, you got it.